# (new to JavaGameMaking)Libgdx random spawning of rectangle(sprite?)

Tags: java, random, libgdx

i want to know how to make a way to spawn multiple different a sprite or rectangle. is it using array?For now the code below spawn the same rectangle(sprite) that spawn at random location every second. so i want it choose itself randomly different rectangle(sprite)?

```
public class Chibi implements ApplicationListener {
Texture fallL;
OrthographicCamera camera;
SpriteBatch batch;
Array<Rectangle> chibis1;
long lastDropTime;



@Override
public void create() {  
    //Load image 
    fallL = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("fallL.png"));

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false,800,400);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    chibis1 = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnChibi();
}

private void spawnChibi() {
    Rectangle chibi1 = new Rectangle();
    chibi1.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800-64);
    chibi1.y = 480;
    chibi1.width = 64;
    chibi1.height = 64;
    chibis1.add(chibi1);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    fallL.dispose();
    bgMusic.dispose();
    points.dispose();
    lvup.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    for(Rectangle chibi1 : chibis1){

        batch.draw(fallL, chibi1.x, chibi1.y);
    }
    batch.end();

    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime >1000000000) spawnChibi();
    //process user input
    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = chibis1.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Rectangle chibi1 = iter.next();
        chibi1.y -= 200*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(chibi1.y + 64 < -60) iter.remove();

    }


}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
}
```

also keep in mind that im new to this java game making and java. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to approach this.

- You could populate an array (or a List, or some other data structure) with some predefined rectangles and sprites. Then you could choose from the data structure randomly when you want to add a rectangle to the world.
- Or you could generate the rectangles on the fly using a random number generator.

Which approach you take depends entirely on your context, which we don't have.

Comment: true. that was the plan i intended to do. i will look into it.

Comment: okay. i will look into it. thanks. i intended to create a spawn instance that consist 4 instance(e.g box,bomb,heart...) which it choose one of these instance randomly every second to spawn on screen and when user clicks it, it will be destroyed